# Cannot login with PhpMyAdmin on Mac os x 10.6. Does anyone know a fix to this error message?

Tags: php, mysql, configuration, macos, phpmyadmin

I just reinstalled Mac Os X 10.6.2 and had to reinstall/update my MySQL server.
I run phpMyAdmin inside my `localhost` and I used to be able to login without a hitch.

Since the updated (latest version MySQL 5.1.45 & PMA 3.3.1) versions I only get the following error when trying to login with phpMyAdmin:

```
phpMyAdmin - Error

Cannot start session without errors, please check errors given in your PHP
and/or webserver log file and configure your PHP installation properly.
```

The only thing I noticed is that mcrypt cannot be loaded (this has always been the case, no idea what to do to install this..) but this has never been a problem before.

If anyone know what to do here that would be really appreciated.

Thanks for reading,

Jannis

PS: The MySQL server itself is running and I am able to login with as root user via the `MySQL Administrator.app`

Comment: Check your PHP log file for messages, and post those messages with your question. That will help us identify your problem. If you don't know where your LOG file is, use phpinfo() to find out.

Comment: How do i enable logging of errors? Currently my phpinfo says: `error_log no value no value` & `log_errors Off Off` I really am not sure how all this works unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Well setting log_errors to `on` would bring error messages to the web-server's error_log. To do so you can use an `.htaccess` file placed in your web root with

```
php_value log_errors = 1
```

in it. It can be not worked but there is some other ways too. You can edit your php.ini for example and restart your server after it.

Without error message it's hard to guess what is really happened. there can be something wrong with session save path or other settings

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I changed my password from within PHPMyAdmin.  The solution was simple.  Clear the browser cache and try to login again.  You should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

I too upgraded to 10.6, actually I got a new mac and migrated my system over, then I installed *phpmyadmin 3.4.2* and was getting messages about not being able to login as well as message about needing mcrypt. I re-installed PHP, now I'm running *PHP Version 5.3.6*.

I had Navicat on my system and was able to log into mysql database without issue. I tried resetting my mysql password, but that would not take. Not sure why. I had no valuable data so I re-installed MySQL, now I'm running *MYSQL 5.5.13*.

Still I could not login with phpMyAdmin - however thanks to new MySQL I was no longer seeing message about needing encyption, but I was getting a #1045 error on phpmyadmin.  I guess it was telling me I had wrong password. Actually I had never set a password! I guess phpMyAdmin didn't like that as it would not allow me to login without a pw.  (as you can see from this post I am not well versed in linux/unix, but I am one persistent fellow!  this took me three nights.)

I entered these in Terminal to set a password, then phpmyadmin worked!

1) Need to first stop the MYSQL server, enter this in Terminal, then hit enter:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql stop
```

2) Then set a password or new password. Needless to say replace 'whatever…" with your password of choice by entering this line in Terminal, and hit enter.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('whateverfornew') WHERE User='root';
```

3) Now flush the privileges by entering this line in Terminal, and hit enter:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

4) Now restart MySQL by entering this line in Terminal, and hit enter:

```
/etc/rc.d/init.d/mysql start
```

5) Now login to your phpmyadmin with username "root" and your new password.

Yep, I know this is rudimentary and I have no idea if I am following best practices but for those of us who are new to Mac / Unix and want to get phpmyadmin, mysql etc running this worked for me.  Personally I found a lot of forums but most already assume that reader is comfortable using terminal and Unix commands…which I am not - I just wanted a working development zone.

Answer (score 0):

Old thread I know, but I've been struggling all day with this.

I'm on MacOSX Lion. Unfortunately, I've been struggling with the same issue all day. In my case however, I was not getting an errors in the php `error_log`. So I was clueless as to what was happening. I finally found a setting in phpMyAdmin's `config.inc.php` and used it like so:

> $cfg['Error_Handler']['display'] = true;

After this I was able to see in the browser itself what the problem was with permissions on the folder specified in `session.save_path` (./tmp which is a symlink to /private/tmp on mac).

However, I'd like to add the setting a 777 to the `session.save_path` folder may not be the right thing to do. I have done the following which seems safer:

```
owner: root (default) 
group: _www (sudo chgrp _www /private/tmp)
```

Then allow the group to read, write and execute using:

```
sudo chmod g+rwx /private/tmp
```

Prevent others from reading, writing or executing in this folder:

```
sudo chmod o-rwx /private/tmp
```